# Can you create a NuGet package of SSRS Reports?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

Is there a way to create a NuGet package of SSRS reports and data sources? I have the following spec, but get the message:

> Cannot create a package that has no dependencies nor content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>Edi.ReportDeployment</id>
        <title>Report Package</title>
        <version>0.1.0000001</version>
        <authors>Clark Associates</authors>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>Holds SSRS reports to be deployed for EDI.</description>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="../../Clark.EDI.Reports/*.rdl" target="Reports" />
        <file src="../Clark.EDI.Reports/*.rds" target="Data Sources" />
    </files>
</package>
```

Our ultimate goal is to have a VSTS Build event use Octopus Deploy to push the reports to our dev server.

Comment: Linking this related question, which states that NuGet Pack is unable to process paths that begin with a . - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38911494/why-does-nugetpack-respond-with-cannot-create-a-package-that-has-no-dependencie