# Why does NuGetPack respond with "Cannot create a package that has no dependencies nor content"

Tags: c#, nuget, cakebuild

I am trying to use the following Cake script:

```
Task("Create-NuGet-Packages")
    .IsDependentOn("Build")
    .WithCriteria(() =>DirectoryExists(parameters.Paths.Directories.NugetNuspecDirectory))
    .Does(() =>
{
    var nuspecFiles = GetFiles(parameters.Paths.Directories.NugetNuspecDirectory + "/**/*.nuspec");

    EnsureDirectoryExists(parameters.Paths.Directories.NuGetPackages);

    foreach(var nuspecFile in nuspecFiles)
    {
        // TODO: Addin the release notes
        // ReleaseNotes = parameters.ReleaseNotes.Notes.ToArray(),

        // Create packages.
        NuGetPack(nuspecFile, new NuGetPackSettings {
            Version = parameters.Version.SemVersion,
            BasePath = parameters.Paths.Directories.PublishedLibraries.Combine(nuspecFile.GetFilenameWithoutExtension().ToString()),
            OutputDirectory = parameters.Paths.Directories.NuGetPackages,
            Symbols = false,
            NoPackageAnalysis = true
        });
    }
});
```

But I keep getting the same error:

[image: Error returned from NuGetPack]

I have confirmed that the generated `*.temp.nuspec` file does indeed contain the correct files, and that the files exist within the specified location, and that the BasePath is correct.

**NOTE:** I have used `-Verbosity Diagnostic` to generate the actual command that is being passed to NuGet.exe, and running that directly also results in the same error message.  As a result, I don't think that this is a problem directly with Cake, but rather with NuGet.exe.

Comment: Make sure you are using latest NuGet. One can run `nuget update -self` to have latest version installed.

Comment: In my case, I found the following comment in that GitHub thread you linked to elucidating: `unfortunately, the way the application is written, will require substantial re-work to determine if something was included as a result of being hardcoded or as a result of wildcard. It's especially more difficult with dotnet.exe pack / msbuild /t:pack where msbuild resolves all the wildcards and passes NuGet a full list of files.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out, this was an error with the directory paths that I was using.  I was trying to use `.build\_temp\_PublishedLibraries\Cake.Twitter`.

Changing `.build` to `BuildArtifacts` immediately made everything work:

[image]

After doing a little bit of digging, this seems to be a known issue with NuGet (well at least known to some):

https://twitter.com/ferventcoder/status/505048107520765952

i.e. Any file or folder that start with a `.` are not recognised by nuget pack.

Seemingly this issue has been corrected in Chocolatey, and as a result, it works there.

**NOTE:** I have raised this as an issue here: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3308

Comment: I found the following comment in that GitHub thread you linked to elucidating: `unfortunately, the way the application is written, will require substantial re-work to determine if something was included as a result of being hardcoded or as a result of wildcard. It's especially more difficult with dotnet.exe pack / msbuild /t:pack where msbuild resolves all the wildcards and passes NuGet a full list of files.` In other words, the problem is that MSBuild may not know you have a .nuspec file that has wildcards in it.

Answer (score 4):

In my case problem was using forward slash `/` instead of backslash `\` - it is probably related to the https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3584

Comment: But in that case, how do i use it on linux?

Answer (score 3):

This error can also be seen if you simply specify a bad path/spec in the `<file src` attribute and NuGet gathers no files.

Comment: For example, on Windows your path should use backslashes instead of forward slashes.